# TXTRecord cannot be set with Bonjour SDK (COM Wrapper to CComObject< CTXTRecord >*)

Tags: c++, com, f#, interop

It looks like Apple Bonjour SDK does not set the TXTRecord while publishing the service because of COM/.NET interop.

In brief, there is a COM class for creating text record:

```
[
  odl,
  uuid(8FA0889C-5973-4FC9-970B-EC15C925D0CE),
  helpstring("ITXTRecord Interface"),
  dual,
  nonextensible,
  oleautomation
]
interface ITXTRecord : IDispatch {
    [id(0x00000001), helpstring("method SetValue")]
    HRESULT SetValue(
                    [in] BSTR key, 
                    [in] VARIANT value);
    ...
};

[
  uuid(AFEE063C-05BA-4248-A26E-168477F49734),
  helpstring("TXTRecord Class")
]
coclass TXTRecord {
    [default] interface ITXTRecord;
};
```

The corresponding C++ code is there: https://github.com/Apple-FOSS-Mirror/mDNSResponder/blob/master/mDNSWindows/DLLX/TXTRecord.cpp#L38

And there is a method for registering the service in the class `IDNSSDService`:

```
    [id(0x00000004), helpstring("method Register")]
    HRESULT Register(
                    [in] DNSSDFlags flags, 
                    [in] unsigned long ifIndex, 
                    [in] BSTR name, 
                    [in] BSTR regtype, 
                    [in] BSTR domain, 
                    [in] BSTR host, 
                    [in] unsigned short port, 
                    [in] ITXTRecord* record, 
                    [in] IDNSSDEventManager* eventManager, 
                    [out, retval] IDNSSDService** service);
```

The corresponding C++ method is there: https://github.com/Apple-FOSS-Mirror/mDNSResponder/blob/master/mDNSWindows/DLLX/DNSSDService.cpp#L494

Then in .NET:

```
    let txtRecord = new TXTRecordClass()
    txtRecord.SetValue("test", "test")
    _service.Register(enum<DNSSDFlags>(0), uint32(0), author, "_webdav._tcp", null, null, uint16(80), txtRecord, _events)
```

SetValue works well and the method CTXTRecord::SetValue was called. The pointer `this` is, let say, 0x004573ec.

The tricky part is that the pointer to `record` in method `Register` is different and does not equal 0x004573ec! It points to some other address, usually not far after the saved pointer (0x004573ec). Ok, maybe it is a some kind of wrapper. The bad thing is that `Publish` later cast it to `CComObject<CTXTRecord>*` but it looks like the referenced object is not initialized (has zerofied fields). I've tried to use different approaches, like passing the `txtRecord` by reference, look for a workaround, but nothing here.

It looks like there is a missing directive in IDL or approach implemented in `Publish` is incorrect, but my .NET/C++/COM interop skills are not good enough to find a solution. Any ideas?

Comment: "*Ok, maybe it is a some kind of wrapper.*" No, it is the manifestation of multiple inheritance, specifically different vtables per base object.

Comment: Do you have more info to read about it? Some article maybe? So the .NET works incorrectly? Or the error in bonjour code?

Comment: It is orthogonal to .NET – it applies to any use of multiple inheritance in C++, and COM objects are affected because they usually implement more than one interface. In native-land the portable solution is to use `IUnknown::QueryInterface` to get the correct address of the base object of interest, but I don't know how this works in .NET, which is why I'm posting comments rather than an answer. ;-] ([`Marshal.QueryInterface`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.queryinterface.aspx) is my best guess at a starting point.)

Comment: Also note that I am only addressing the discrepancy between the value of `this` and the value of the saved pointer, i.e. attempting to describe that this is normal and expected. I don't have a clue about the rest of your question.

Comment: Does it actually work with a C++ client?  [This is a really ugly hack](https://github.com/Apple-FOSS-Mirror/mDNSResponder/blob/master/mDNSWindows/DLLX/DNSSDService.cpp#L584), it should be using a private interface.

Comment: It seems it has [a .NET wrapper](https://github.com/Apple-FOSS-Mirror/mDNSResponder/blob/master/mDNSWindows/DLL.NET/dnssd_NET.cpp#L675) too.

Comment: Please excuse the comment semi-spam, but maybe the current apartment where a `TXTRecord` is created and `_service`'s apartment are not the same, so that ugly hack is probably casting a COM proxy.  Are you using this across processes?

Comment: Paulo, thank you for your comments. I suspect that there is something wrong on Bonjour's side because there is definitely no room for error on .NET side - everything I have is just a STA thread start function. No inter-process or inter-thread communications.

Answer (score 2):

That COM wrapper has a [really ugly hack](https://github.com/Apple-FOSS-Mirror/mDNSResponder/blob/master/mDNSWindows/DLLX/DNSSDService.cpp#L584):

```
STDMETHODIMP CDNSSDService::Register(DNSSDFlags flags, ULONG ifIndex, BSTR serviceName, BSTR regType, BSTR domain, BSTR host, USHORT port, ITXTRecord *record, IDNSSDEventManager *eventManager, IDNSSDService **service)
{
    // ...

    if ( record )
    {
        CComObject< CTXTRecord > * realTXTRecord;

        realTXTRecord = ( CComObject< CTXTRecord >* ) record;

        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

Which is doomed to fail with marshaled interface pointers, from objects that belong to a different apartment.  I guess your `ITXTRecord` is being created in another process, thus in another apartment, so that cast is taking a COM proxy instead of the actual object.

One way you have to work around this is to find a way to grab a reference to a `TXTRecord` object created by the COM server.  I found two places in the COM wrapper ([here](https://github.com/Apple-FOSS-Mirror/mDNSResponder/blob/master/mDNSWindows/DLLX/DNSSD.cpp#L635) and [here](https://github.com/Apple-FOSS-Mirror/mDNSResponder/blob/master/mDNSWindows/DLLX/DNSSDService.cpp#L1590)) that create the object and two places ([here](https://github.com/Apple-FOSS-Mirror/mDNSResponder/blob/master/mDNSWindows/DLLX/DNSSD.cpp#L654) and [here](https://github.com/Apple-FOSS-Mirror/mDNSResponder/blob/master/mDNSWindows/DLLX/DNSSDService.cpp#L1620)) where that object is provided to the client.

Following references, it seems you must call <strike>either [`CDNSSD::Resolve`](https://github.com/Apple-FOSS-Mirror/mDNSResponder/blob/master/mDNSWindows/DLLX/DNSSD.cpp#L70) with a `IResolveListener` or</strike><sup>1.</sup> [`CDNSSDService::Resolve`](https://github.com/Apple-FOSS-Mirror/mDNSResponder/blob/master/mDNSWindows/DLLX/DNSSDService.cpp#L1590) with a `IDNSSDEventManager`, pointing to an object that also implements `_IDNSSDEvents` (this can be your own object) which will receive a "real" `ITXTRecord` as an argument to the `ServiceResolved` event method.

As such, you can make a dummy resolve with a smart event handler that grabs the `TXTRecord`.  If you find a reliable host (e.g. localhost, or 127.0.0.1), you may probably turn this into a factory method.  I didn't actually test this, but from the code, if the host doesn't have a TXT record, you'll just get an empty one.

---

1. I can't find DNSSD.h to check on `IResolveListener` and the declaration of `CDNSSD` itself.